# failing to execute without arguments, input not parsed correctly

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

In my function below, I am trying to read several sentences from stdin and process them once the user hits enter twice. I assign memory dynamically to the entire buffer (set of lines) as depicted. I am running into:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./myfunc
```

Minimal compiling snippet:

```
void myfunc(void) {

    int textsize = BUF_SIZE;
    char **lines = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * textsize);
    int linecount = 0;
    char text[BUF_SIZE];

    while ((strcpy(text, fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin))) != NULL) {
        if (text[0] == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        lines[linecount] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(text));
        strcpy(lines[linecount], text);
        linecount++;
    }
    for (int index = linecount - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", lines[index]);
        /* if line has newline stripped, else printf("%s", lines[index]);*/
    }

    free(*lines);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(text, fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin))` What do you think will happen when `fgets` returns `NULL`?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(text));` should be `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(text)+1));` as strings in C have an extra byte for the terminating NUL character. The type for `sizeof` is wrong and will result in a too large buffer but should be changed for correctness.

Comment: OT: `exit(0);` That's not technically wrong but is generally not a good thing to do. Functions should rarely cause the whole program to exit (a common exception is if a fatal error is encountered).

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the input!
a) when fgets receives NULL, would it mean the scnario that the stdin simply received two return keys?

b) I incorporated the +1, but don't follow the 'The type for sizeof is wrong' part. Say BUF_SIZE is 512, it would mean 512 pointer references to each sentece separately, no?

c) Noted. I replaced that with return 0

Comment: regarding: *Minimal compiling snippet:*   the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the statements: `#include <stdio.h` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h.`

Comment: there are a few other problems in the posted code.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the value of textsize in this memory allocation

```
char **lines = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * textsize);
```

does not make a sense.

Using strcpy in the condition of the while loop

```
while ((strcpy(text, fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin))) != NULL) {
```

also does not make a sense because 1) `fgets` can return `NULL` 2) and if `fgets` did not return `NULL` then it already filled the array text with a string.

So the loop should be written at least like

```
while ( fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
```

In this statement

```
lines[linecount] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(text));
```

you need to allocate an array of object of the type `char` instead of the type `char *` and the number of the allocated elements should be equal tp `strlen( text ) + 1`.

This call

```
free(*lines);
```

frees only the first allocated element pointed to by the pointer `lines` but you need to free all the allocated memory.

And this call in the end of the function

```
exit(0);
```

again does not make a sense. At least you could write

```
return;
```

or just remove the call of `exit`.

The function can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE    100

void myfunc( void ) 
{
    char **lines = NULL;
    size_t linecount = 0;
    
    char text[BUF_SIZE];
    int success = 1;

    while ( success && fgets( text, BUF_SIZE, stdin ) != NULL && text[0] != '\n' ) 
    {
        char **tmp = realloc( lines, ( linecount + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );
        success = tmp != NULL;
        
        if ( success )
        {
            lines = tmp;
            lines[linecount] = malloc( ( strlen( text ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
            
            success = lines[linecount] != NULL;
            
            if ( success )
            {
                strcpy( lines[linecount], text );
                ++linecount;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( !success ) fputs( "Nor all input records were successfully stored\n", stdout );
    
    for ( size_t i = linecount; i != 0; ) 
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "%s", lines[--i]);
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < linecount; ++i )
    {
        free( lines[i] );
    }
    free( lines );
}

int main(void) 
{
    myfunc();
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter strings

```
Hello
World
```

then the output will be

```
World 
Hello
```

Comment: Here's my understanding, please correct me:
1. fgets 100 characters from stdin and while it isn't '\n' or return key, you process further.

2. you create a pointer to another pointer to which you allocate 1 byte? ( linecount + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) is a small buffer, isn't it?

3. Once allocated, you allocate memory to the first pointer in lines[ ]. size of that is governed by whatever was read in static array 'text'. But what if fgets reads 500 characters and BUF_SIZE is only 100. 

4. you copy the read line into lines[i] when memory allocation was succesful.
I got the rest.

Comment: @ankitrana_ l ines points to a dynamically allocated array of pointers. Then a new string is read you need to reallocate the array for one more pointer that will point to a dynamically allocated array for the given string, So this expression ( linecount + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) specifies the size of the reallocated array. If you wiil eneter a string with 500 characters then the loop will iterate two times because the string will be read by fgets as two strings.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! I wonder if there is a way to do it without creating double pointers? Using malloc but at best with a char *. Drawbacks if any with that?

Comment: @ankitrana_ You could declare a two-dimensional array with sufficient number of elements. But this approach can be inefficient because either there will be allocate too much memory or the user can enter more strings then the size of the array.

Comment: I was htinking more about this. Do you think instead of using fgets(), maybe using getline() to read from stdin will make things simpler?

Comment: @ankitrana_ You may use getline but it is not a standard C function.

Comment: I think with POSIX ext support, it should work on my setup. I started modifying your  snippet but using getline, running into a fundamental memory handling issue.  See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131225/using-getline-along-with-dynamic-storage
Thanks!