# Using getline along with dynamic storage

Tags: c, malloc, file-handling, getline

I have the following snippet. I have come across several examples where one can read a line using getline and then simply print it. I am struggling to continuously save from stdin, read using getline() and probably have a buffer of some sort to keep track of all that is read (is it needed?).

Eventually, I just print the contents in reverse order of the user's input last line first.
I am not sure if char* can point to the entire buffer os stdin input, that we can reverse read eventually.

This is running into segmentation fault, my best guess would be around accessing memory that was never allocated.

```
  size_t linecount = 0;
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  size_t nbytes = 100;
  char *content;

  if (1) {
    my_string = (char*) malloc(nbytes + 1);
    while ((bytes_read = getline(&my_string, &nbytes, stdin)) >= 0
        && my_string[0] != '\n') {
      puts(my_string);
      printf("read: %ld bytes", bytes_read);
      content = (char*) malloc((strlen(my_string) + 1) * sizeof(char));
      success = content != NULL;

      if (success) {
        strcpy(content, my_string);
        ++linecount;
      } else {
        printf("Malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: _segmentation fault_ due to unposted code.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: If you declare `char *my_string = NULL;` and `size_t nbytes = 0;`, then `getline()` will handle the allocation, as needed, for any length input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin DO you mean I don't need dynamic memory allocation to char * content that I have? 
Sounds like my_string will basically become the entire buffer with multiple sentences separated by \n ? is that right?

I am not sure in that case how do I reverse the order of the lines? Because I was aiming to have a line count and maybe a pointer that goes from line to line as line-count decrements from size to 1.

Comment: I wrote up an answer for you explaining the use of `getline()`. If you want to store each line for later use, let me know and I can add an additional example to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal is "print the contents in reverse order of the user's input, last line first", the program must store all the lines.  The `getline()` function typically allocates quite a large space for each line (128 bytes by default on my Mac, and growing if input lines are longer than that), so it is usually best to have a buffer managed by `getline()` that can grow if need be, and to copy the actual input strings somewhere else with the requisite length.  I use `strdup()` to copy the line.

```
/* Read file and print the lines in reverse order */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char **ptrs = 0;
    size_t numptrs = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char  *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;

    while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)
    {
        if (count == numptrs)
        {
            size_t newnum = (numptrs + 2) * 2;
            void *newptrs = realloc(ptrs, newnum * sizeof(*ptrs));
            if (newptrs == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", newnum * sizeof(*ptrs));
                exit(1);
            }
            ptrs = newptrs;
            numptrs = newnum;
        }
        ptrs[count++] = strdup(buffer);
    }

    free(buffer);

    /* Print lines in reverse order */
    for (size_t i = count; i > 0; i--)
        fputs(ptrs[i-1], stdout);

    /* Free allocated memory */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        free(ptrs[i]);
    free(ptrs);

    return 0;
}
```

It's easy to argue that the code should check that `strdup()` succeeds and take appropriate action if it does not.  The code freeing the allocated memory should be in a function — that would make clean up after an error easier, too.  The code could be revised into a function that could be used to process files listed as command-line arguments instead of standard input.

Given this text as standard input:

```
Because it messes up the order in which people normally read text.
> Why is top-posting such a bad thing?
>> Top-posting.
>>> What is the most annoying thing in e-mail?
```

the program produces the output:

```
>>> What is the most annoying thing in e-mail?
>> Top-posting.
> Why is top-posting such a bad thing?
Because it messes up the order in which people normally read text.
```

Comment: Quick ques or 2. If realloc() is needed to adjust buffer size with getline() then how is auto-sizing an advantage of getline() over fgets()?

Also, I am not sure how you executed your snippet particularly marking the EO Input. I had to include && buffer[0] != '\n' to look for a return key. It would be nice to know how to look for a signal that marks EOF for stdin instead. @Jonathan

Comment: The `getline()` is unusual in that it is defined to return `-1` rather than `EOF` on EOF (though the two values are normally the same).  The loop `while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)` detects EOF by looking for `-1`.  In this code, I keep passing the same buffer pointer and length variables to `getline()`, so it automatically grows the buffer to be big enough for the longest line in the input.  The sample data doesn't stress it, but it would handle a megabyte of JSON on a single line with equal aplomb.

Comment: My code is reallocating the array of pointers to the lines that are read; it is simply copying the data out of the buffer used by `getline()` by calling `strdup()` to allocate and copy.  Testing for `buffer[0] != '\n'` would test for empty lines — lines consisting of only a newline.  The `getline()` function doesn't return until it encounters a newline or EOF, or it cannot allocate any more memory.  The data for a line won't be available to `getline()` until you hit return at the end of line — that's routine behaviour for POSIX systems.

Comment: I hope those two comments are addressing your concerns.  If not, ask (comment) again for clarification.

Comment: I understood the memory allocation part of your comment. let me rephrase what puzzles me. Say i execute this code and I am providing input from stdin then:

A) how what on stdin input will inform getline() that it has to jump out of the while loop? At this point this snippet would keep on taking several lines (empty or otherwise).

B) I am keen on say after entering 5 lines from stdin I want to do something like ctrl+c or ctrl+d and instead of going to the terminal prompt, it should print the reversal part of the code. @Jonathan

Comment: If the input is coming from a file (`./revlines83 < top-posting.txt`), then the system knows when the end of the file is reached and reports that with a `read()` system call that returns 0 bytes of data.  If the input is coming from you typing at the terminal, then you need to know how to indicate EOF.  On POSIX systems, that is most often the control-D key combination, but it is configurable via the `stty` command.  On Windows systems, that is usually the control-Z key combination.   There are some ifs and buts around that.   _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If, for example, you've not yet hit return, then typing control-D sends the line so far to the terminal driver, which in turn makes that information available to programs.  It does not, however, send "0 bytes read" — you'd have to hit control-D again (before typing anything else) to indicate EOF.  If you just hit return though, then control-D will cause `read()` to return 0 bytes indicating EOF immediately.

Comment: If you want to stop after 5 lines, you can add a counter to the loop control.  You might do `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { if (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) == -1) break; … }` for example.  That will read up to 5 lines and then stop the loop.  Handling control-C interrupts is considerably trickier — you need to use POSIX [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)
(or perhaps standard C `signal()`, but it gives you less control) to detect the interrupts and then break the loop.  That's far afield from this question, though.

Comment: I see. Yes, in my case it is purely stdin. And I think one ctrl+D combination single check should suffice since I want to send only one set of stdin input process it and then exit (0) after printing the reveres order.

Comment: The number of lines could be variable so the for loop with a const upper bound might not be the way for me.

Comment: You have many options — the key point is that you type control-D at the terminal after hitting return to indicate EOF.  If you want to control the loop in other ways, you can build that into your code too.  You should always be prepared for EOF before you expected it; you can't afford not to handle the return value from `getline()` — or any other input function — properly.

Comment: Ok, so knowing "In Linux, the EOF signal can be sent on the command line via CTRL+D."
How would your while loop look to accommodate this?

Comment: It looks exactly like the code in my answer — it handles EOF correctly.

Comment: One last ques on the subject suppose it was 
while (fgets(&my_string, &nbytes, stdin) != NULL), we expect a NULL to be returned when there is an EOF marked by Ctrl+D in this case and that should be equivalent to what we discussed? Correct?

Comment: Basically, yes.  The main caveat is that with `getline()`, you will get the complete line, but `fgets()` uses a fixed-size buffer and if the next line is too long, it will be split, with the first call putting as much information as will fit into the buffer leaving the residue to be read on subsequent calls.  If you choose a sensible buffer size (such as 4096), then you're unlikely to run into problems.  One other gotcha is that with `getline()`, you can process files containing null bytes because it tells you how many bytes were read; with `fgets()`, you can't reliably do that.

Comment: Thanks make sense. It's time we have getline() as standard C haha.
Appreciate the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Reading with `getline()`, if you provide a pointer initialized `NULL` and the size argument initialized zero, then `getline()` will allocate sufficient storage for your input -- regardless of the length. If you are simply reversing the string, then there is no reason to allocate additional storage. You only need to allocate additional storage if you want to save multiple lines read by `getline()` in a collection (such as when using an array of pointers, e.g. `char *lines[NLINES];`, or pointer-to-pointer, e.g. `char **lines;`)

To read all lines of input with `getline()`, after opening your files (or simply assigning `stdin` to the `FILE*` pointer), you need no more than:

```
    char *lineptr = NULL;       /* pointer for getline() set NULL */
    size_t n = 0;               /* n set to 0, getline() allocates */
    ...
    while (getline (&lineptr, &n, fp) != -1)    /* read every line from file */
        ...
```

If you are simply reversing the characters in each line, you can write a simple string reversal function and output the reversed string. The `getline()` read loop with a function called `strrev()` that takes the string as an argument would be:

```
    while (getline (&lineptr, &n, fp) != -1)        /* read every line from file */
        fputs (strrev (lineptr), stdout);           /* reverse line & output */
```

Crafting your `strrev()` function to handle the string regardless of whether a `'\n'` is present allows you to simply pass the line from `getline()` containing the `'\n'` character at the end, without having to trim the newline from the string first. If you did want to remove the `'\n'`, you can use the number of characters returned by `getline()`, or a simple call to `strcspn()` is all that is required, e.g.

```
    while (getline (&lineptr, &n, fp) != -1) {  /* read every line from file */
        lineptr[strcspn (lineptr, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim '\n' from end of lineptr */
        /* do whatever else is desired */
    }
```

Putting it altogether, and taking the filenames to read as the first argument to the program (or reading from `stdin` by default if no argument is given), you could do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* getline() is POSIX not standard C */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strrev (char *str);       /* function to reverse string in-place         */
                                /* (str must be mutable, not a string-literal) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char *lineptr = NULL;       /* pointer for getline() set NULL */
    size_t n = 0;               /* n set to 0, getline() allocates */
    
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (&lineptr, &n, fp) != -1)        /* read every line from file */
        fputs (strrev (lineptr), stdout);           /* reverse line & output */
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    free (lineptr);    /* getline() allocates, so don't forget to free the memory */
}

/** strrev - reverse string, swaps src & dest each iteration up to '\n'.
 *  Takes valid string and reverses, original is not preserved.
 *  If str is valid, returns pointer to str, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *strrev (char *str)
{
    if (!str) {     /* validate str not NULL */
        printf ("%s() error: invalid string\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!*str)      /* check empty string */
        return str;
    
    char *begin = str,
         *end = begin + strcspn (str, "\n") - 1;

    while (end > begin)
    {
        char tmp = *end;
        *end--   = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Reading from `stdin` and using <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> when done (<kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows):

```
$ ./bin/getline_strrev
My dog has fleas
saelf sah god yM
My cat has none!
!enon sah tac yM
Lucky cat...
...tac ykcuL
```

Reading (or redirecting) input from a file:

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/dog.txt
My dog has fleas
My cat has none!
Lucky cat...
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_strrev dat/dog.txt
saelf sah god yM
!enon sah tac yM
...tac ykcuL
```

Redirecting the file on `stdin`:

```
$ ./bin/getline_strrev < dat/dog.txt
saelf sah god yM
!enon sah tac yM
...tac ykcuL
```

---

**Reversing Lines Not Characters**

Given your clarification in the comments, you can store an unknown number of lines of unknown length by allocating pointers (and reallocating as required) and allocating storage for each line, assigning the address of the block to hold each line to each of your pointers in turn and then copying the line read by `getline()` to the allocated block. You have two types of memory to content with, the block of memory holding pointers, and the blocks of memory holding each line. This is explained in great detail in [How to read a text file and store in an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66116048/3422102) from a day or two ago.

The only different between that example and here is the use of `getline()` instead of `fgets()` and the minor changes to how to compute the number of characters in each line and remove the ending `'\n'` from the buffer are trivially different, just due to `getline()` returning the number of characters read. Reversing the order of the lines is also different (but also a trivial difference)

The changes for `getline()` and reversing the lines are:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTRS 2     /* initial number of pointers to allocated */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char **lines = NULL,        /* pointer to all lines */
        *lineptr = NULL;        /* pointer for getline() set NULL */
    size_t  n = 0,              /* n set to 0, getline() allocates */
            nptrs = NPTRS,      /* no. of pointers to allocate */
            used = 0;           /* no. of pointers used */
    ssize_t nchr;               /* no. of chars read by getline() */
    
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* allocate initial nptrs pointers - validate EVERY allocation */
    if ((lines = malloc (nptrs * sizeof *lines)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-lines");
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* read every line from file, saving characters read in nchr */
    while ((nchr = getline (&lineptr, &n, fp)) != -1) {
        if (nchr > 0 && lineptr[nchr-1] == '\n')    /* if chars read and \n */
            lineptr[--nchr] = 0;                    /* trim \n from end */
        if (used == nptrs) {
            /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, (2 * nptrs) * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {                             /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-lines");
                break;                              /* don't exit, lines still good */
            }
            lines = tmp;                            /* assign reallocated block */
            nptrs *= 2;                             /* update number of pointers */
        }
        /* allocate storage for line, assign address for new block to lines[used] */
        if (!(lines[used] = malloc (nchr + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc-lines[used]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[used], lineptr, nchr + 1);    /* copy line to new block of mem */
        
        used += 1;      /* increment used pointer counter */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
        
    /* output lines in reverse order */
    while (used--) {
        puts (lines[used]);
        free (lines[used]);     /* free storage for each string when done */ 
    }
    free (lines);               /* free pointers */
    
    free (lineptr);             /* free memory allocated by getline() */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Same inpt file for example as above.

```
$ ./bin/getline_linerev dat/dog.txt
Lucky cat...
My cat has none!
My dog has fleas
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getline_linerev dat/dog.txt
==6502== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6502== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6502== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6502== Command: ./bin/getline_linerev dat/dog.txt
==6502==
Lucky cat...
My cat has none!
My dog has fleas
==6502==
==6502== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6502==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6502==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 5,887 bytes allocated
==6502==
==6502== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6502==
==6502== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6502== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over an let me know if you have further questions or need additional help.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate explanation. Appreciate it!
The objective is to reverse order of the lines but not letter by letter. just the sequence in which they appear. And for that I am under the impression there is no way around using malloc and realloc both with a char** to point to all the bunch of different sentences that come from stdin. Correct me if otherwise?

Comment: You are correct, I'll drop an update showing how. Is there any max of lines you will deal with? If you you can avoid the 2-step allocating/reallocating pointers and allocating for lines. Let me know so I'll know which you are interested in. A full explanation for allocating, reallocating pointers is here [How to read a text file and store in an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66116048/3422102) using `fgets()` instead of `getline()`, but the implementation is identical otherwise. With a fixed max number of lines, you avoid having to allocate/reallocate pointers.